# ¿Cómo escribir correctamente este query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas, una de productos y otra de categorías, joineadas

Quiero que me traiga todos los productos que cumplen con dos condiciones obligatorias, que son:

- Productos que están en la categoría 1 (condición 1)
- Productos que están en la categoría 2 o la categoría 3 (condición 2)

Las dos condiciones son obligatorias.

Entiendo que la query básicamente sería algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM productos INNER JOIN categorias ON productos.id_producto=categorias.id_producto
WHERE (lacategoria=1) AND (lacategoria=2 or lacategoria=3)
```

Por supuesto en la tabla hay un producto que cumple con esta condición (en mi ejemplo el 77), es decir, está en la categoriía 1, la 2 y la 3, pero al ejecutar en mysql este select me trae 0 resultados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien intenté con IN:

```
SELECT * FROM productos INNER JOIN categorias ON productos.id_producto=categorias.id_producto
WHERE lacategoria IN (1) AND lacategoria IN (2,3);
```

Pero tampoco trae nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La consulta no devolverá nunca nada porque es imposible que una fila (no producto) de tu resultado tenga el valor 1 y a la vez 2 (o 1 y a la vez 3) en el campo `lacategoria`. Puedes colocar el esquema de las tablas, para entender que es lo que realmente estas tratando de lograr?

Comment: podrias aclarar que base de datos estas usando?

Comment: Se trata de un filtro de busqueda para un listado de productos, tipo mercadolibre. Por ejemplo puedo filtrar por Tipo de producto (oficina, industrial, hogar) y por capacidad (litros) (100 litros, 200 litros, 300 liltros). Por eso cuando un usuario selecciona que traiga productos de hogar y oficina, con capacidad de 100 o 300 litros, tienen que buscar en la tabla de productos - categorias los que coinciden con dicha busqueda. Algo asi como where uso IN (hogar, oficina) AND capacidad IN (100,300 litros).

Comment: No pongo las tablas porque son mas complejas,puse un ejemplo simple del tema pero que es igual a mi problema

Comment: utilizo mysql, php y luego lo tengo que llevar a laravel

Comment: Tu consulta podría funcionar, digamos, _forzosamente_. He introducido en la tabla `categorias` un campo `categoria` del tipo varchar para que puedas ver que talvez deberías replantear el diseño de tus tablas. **[Aquí hay una prueba](http://rextester.com/IWQ30075)**, el producto `Pan` cumple los criterios de tu consulta, pero no veo qué sentido tendría diseñar las tablas de esa manera.

Comment: es 1  2 tablas primero que nada eso no queda claro...

Comment: Tal vez no logro comprender tu pregunta. Pero me parece inconsistente que un producto este relacionado con mas de una categoria... yo entiendo tu consulta de la siguiente manera: ``` SELECT * FROM productos INNER JOIN categorias ON productos.id_producto=categorias.id_producto WHERE (lacategoria=1) OR (lacategoria=2 or lacategoria=3)``` Me parece que lo anterior no es lo que deseas..Tienes algun ejemplo de la entrada y salida que esperas obtener?

Answer (score 1):

Inténtalo así:

```
SELECT * FROM productos INNER JOIN categorias ON productos.id_producto=categorias.id_producto
WHERE (lacategoria>=1) AND (lacategoria<=3)
```

Comment: gracias Gerry, pero el ejemplo que di  es solo una abstracción del problema, lo que realmente intento hacer es un filtro de selección algo mas complejo (ver jpg tabla). Gracias igualmente!

Answer (score 0):

como bien señala Carlos, tu pregunta es imposible de resolver asi como esta la tabla en este momento.

Si analizamos tu query, la clausula where le dice:

```
(lacategoria=1) AND (lacategoria=2 or lacategoria=3)
```

que por cada fila (no el total, cada fila) tenga en el campo lacategoria 1 y tambien lacategoria = 2 o 3.. y eso es imposible...

vos estas buscando que existan registros con categoria 1 y 2 o 3, entonces vamos a tener que hacer otra cosa...

Fijate y prueba con algo asi:

```
select * from categoria c where (c.lacategoria = 2 or c.lacategoria = 3) and
exist(select * from docs d where lacategoria = 1 and c.id_producto = d.id_producto);
```

En el caso de tu query completo, seria algo asi:

```
SELECT * FROM productos a INNER JOIN rel3_cat4_prod1 b 
ON rel3_cat4_prod1.rel3_id_productos=productos1.prod1_id_produc‌​tos 
WHERE (rel3_id_categorias=42 OR rel3_id_categorias=113) 
AND EXIST 
    (SELECT * FROM rel3_cat4_prod1 p WHERE p.rel3_id_categorias=55 
    AND b.rel3_id_productos=a.rel3_id_productos);
```

Comment: ahi borre los comentarios, la primera vez que uso stackoverflow

Comment: no hay ningun problema.. Bienvenido y lo estas haciendo muy bien! Recuerda leer [tour] si no lo hiciste, y cuando tengas una respuesta que te sirva, aceptarla!

Comment: probe la ultima query que subiste, donde modificaste mi codigo, pero tambien me tira error, estoy revisando

Comment: lo que pasa es que sin ver el diseno de tu tabla real se hace muy dificil.. porque no usas un fiddle para crear un ejemplo que podamos trabajar?

Comment: ahi subi un png de mi tabla rel3_cat4_prod1, que es justo sobre la que hago los where y trato de filtrar. Esta joinea a una de productos, que muestra los resultados de los mismos al hacer una busqueda

Comment: intentando con:  SELECT * FROM productos1 a INNER JOIN rel3_cat4_prod1 r 
ON r.rel3_id_productos=a.prod1_id_productos 
WHERE (r.rel3_id_categorias=42 OR r.rel3_id_categorias=113) 
AND EXIST 
(SELECT * FROM productos1 p INNER JOIN rel3_cat4_prod1 z 
ON z.rel3_id_productos=p.prod1_id_productos 
WHERE z.rel3_id_categorias=55 AND p.prod1_id_produc‌tos=a.prod1_id_produc‌​tos);

Comment: me tira error pero no veo nada mal en la query

Comment: sigo insistiendo y no se porque no me haces caso, adentro del exists no va ningun INNER JOIN... y fijate, ahi modifique el query.. pero no lo estoy probando en ningun lado...

Comment: estoy probando sin el join dentro del exists, tal cual la modificaste

Comment: En mi humilde opinión, no es un problema de consulta, sino de diseño. La consulta, como está planteada en la pregunta, funcionaría _forzosamente_ **[como se muestra en el enlace](http://rextester.com/IWQ30075)**, pero funcionaría creo yo a un precio muy alto, como podría ser el tener datos redundantes, por eso he querido agregar un hipotético campo `categoria` del tipo varchar en la tabla `categorias`.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quieres hacer dos condiciones y que te devuelva los valores que tienen como categoría 1, 2 o 3.

Entiendo que al hacer la consulta no quieres diferenciar entre los que tienen categoría 1 y los que tienen categoría 2 o 3, de esta forma se me ocurre una solución:

```
SELECT * FROM productos INNER JOIN categorias ON productos.id_producto=categorias.id_producto WHERE (lacategoria=1 OR lacategoria=2 OR lacategoria=3);
```

O otra posible solución podría ser:

```
SELECT * FROM productos INNER JOIN categorias ON productos.id_producto=categorias.id_producto WHERE (lacategoria=1) OR (lacategoria>=2 AND lacategoria<=3);
```

O una todavía mas simple:

```
SELECT * FROM productos INNER JOIN categorias ON productos.id_producto=categorias.id_producto WHERE (lacategoria>=1 AND lacategoria<=3);
```

Espero haber entendido tu consulta y que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que buscas creo que es más sencilla de lo que parece:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM productos
 INNER JOIN categoria ON productos.id_producto = categorias.id_producto
  WHERE productos.lacategoria = 1
  AND productos.id_producto IN (SELECT id_producto FROM productos WHERE lacategoria = 2 OR  
  lacategoria = 3)
```

Si bien he entendido tu problema quieres seleccionar todos los productos que tengan categoría 1 y además este contenga una categoría 2 o 3 al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, les comento que por un tema de tiempos y laboral lo que hice fue generar una tablita en la db donde si figuran las categorias para cada id de producto unico, es decir, cada id ahora tiene en un mismo registro algo asi, un array con las categorias de ese producto: ["33","17","48","53","45","52"], por lo cual, ahi ya pude hacer una query simple y obtener el resultado que el buscador necesita.

Las categorias que antes, para un producto en aprticular, estaban en varios registros, ahora estan en uno solo, simplificando el tema.

Y busco con:

```
SELECT * FROM productos1 p INNER JOIN relfiltro r ON r.idprod=p.prod1_id_productos
WHERE r.idcat like '%"55"%' AND (r.idcat like '%"42"%' OR r.idcat like '%"113"%');
```

Tema aparte, para no quedarme con esta solución que fue mas que nada modificar estructura pero no encontrar la query adecuada, voy a testear cada una de las respuestas que me dieron (asi de paso aprendo bien el tema ya que la situación volvera a presentarse en breve). Agradezco enormemente el valioso tiempo que cada uno se tomo en analizar el problema y aportar soluciones!!.

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras solucion. Recuerda leer [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tus respuestas. Un saludo